# MySQL JOIN + Subquery Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to fetch 100 posts and order them by the number of times they've been "remixed" in the last week. Here is my query thus far:

```
SELECT COUNT(remixes.post_id) AS count, posts.title
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM remixes WHERE created_at >= 1343053513
) AS remixes ON posts.id = remixes.post_id
GROUP BY posts.id 
ORDER BY count DESC, posts.created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This produces the correct result; however, after running `DESCRIBE` I get this:

[image: Result of the DESCRIBE syntax]

And here are my indexes on `posts`:

[image: Posts Indexes]

And my indexes on `remixes`:

[image: Remixes Indexes]

And here are my questions:

1. Can you explain what the terms used in the extra column are *really* trying to tell me?
2. Could you provide tips on how I can optimize this query so that it'll scale better.

Thanks in advance!

#### Update

Per Zane's solution, I've updated my query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(remixes.post_id) AS count, posts.title
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN remixes ON posts.id = remixes.post_id AND remixes.created_at >= 1343053513
GROUP BY posts.id 
ORDER BY count DESC, posts.created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
```

And here's the latest `DESCRIBE`

[image: LATEST DESCRIBE]

I'm still worried about the `filesort` part. Any ideas?

Comment: The obvious optimisation would be denormalising your schema to keep an appropriately indexed remix counter in the `posts` table instead of having to count and sort them every time the query runs.

Comment: Thanks. I have that already for *total remixes* but I need to limit that down to those in the *last week*.

Comment: What you want to avoid is having to iterate over all the posts every time, that's the part that grows without bound. I'm not sure how you'd avoid this in a simple way. One thing that comes to mind is using a background job to keep a running tally in a `remixes_past_week` column that updates, say, hourly. E.g. the job runs Aug 10th 12:00, you look at all the remixes made on Aug 3rd between 11:00 and 12:00, substract them from the tallies for the respective posts, then look at remixes made Aug 10th between 11:00 and 12:00, and add them to the respective tallies.

Comment: I was thinking about a background worker, but was trying to get around that if possible. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to wrap your `JOIN` in a sub-select as this will create an unindexed temporary table to store the result of the subselect in, where it then joins on that unindexed table.

Instead, put `created_at` as an additional join condition when joining the remixes table:

```
SELECT 
    a.title, COUNT(b.post_id) AS remixcnt
FROM 
    posts a
LEFT JOIN 
    remixes b ON a.id = b.post_id AND b.created_at >= 1343053513
GROUP BY 
    a.id, a.title
ORDER BY 
    remixcnt DESC, a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: @JesseBunch, the reason why it's not using any keys is because there is no need to. You are not specifying any filtering in the `WHERE` clause, so it simply returns `ALL` rows from posts.

Comment: @JesseBunch if you're interested in learning more about `DESCRIBE`/`EXPLAIN`, take a look at [this awesome presentation](http://www.percona.com/webinars/2012-02-22-explain-demystified/) by Baron Schwartz

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that

```
SELECT COUNT(remixes.post_id) AS count, posts.title
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM remixes WHERE created_at >= 1343053513
) AS remixes ON posts.id = remixes.post_id
GROUP BY posts.id 
ORDER BY count DESC, posts.created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
```

could be rewritten as

```
SELECT COUNT(r.post_id) AS count, posts.title
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN remixes r ON posts.id = r.post_id
WHERE r.created_at >= 1343053513
GROUP BY posts.id 
ORDER BY count DESC, posts.created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
```

which should give you a better `EXPLAIN` plan and run faster.

Comment: Not quite. I want the query to also returns posts where the remix count is zero. Is that possible with your optimization?

Comment: I believe so, but try it out to see. If `COUNT(r.post_id)` is returning NULL, simply wrap it in an `IFNULL()`. For example: `IFNULL(COUNT(r.post_id), 0)`